# Как убрать круглое отображение значков на яндекс картах?

Tags: javascript, css, яндекс-карты

[image: карта]

как я могу убрать их или сделать прозрачными? спасибо!

Comment: Но потом при приближении показывать их как множество "запятых"?

Comment: @EzioMercer можно и так, или просто сделать прозрачными

Comment: https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/cluster_custom_balloon_content_layout - Делайте с ними что хотите)